# kera cross validation strategy?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, cross-validation, grid-search

I am using Keras wrapper for Scikitlearn grid search. My question is: When I have specified the validation data in the fit method AND specifying the cv= 3 default value is being used, So how do this keras GridSeacrhCV will do cross validation? Will it still make 3 folds in training data for cross validation or will it use my already specified validation data 3 times for validation?

[image] ?

```
def grid_create_model(learn_rate=0.1, momentum=0,  optimizer="adam", activation ="softmax", dropout_rate=0.0, weight_constraint=0):
model = Sequential()

if optimizer in ["sgd"]:
    optimizer = SGD(lr=learn_rate, momentum=momentum) 
if optimizer in ["rmsprop'"]:
    optimizer = RMSprop(lr=learn_rate)
if optimizer in ['adam']:
    optimizer = Adam(lr=learn_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)



model.add(Dense(units = 200,input_dim =indim, kernel_initializer= 'normal', activation=activation))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(Dense(units=outdim, activation = "softmax"))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])
return model    
iterations     =  int(parser[section_name]['iterations'])
    epochs         =  [int(parser[section_name]['epochs'])]
    learn_rate     =  list(map(float,[e.strip() for e in parser[section_name]['lr'].split(',')]))
    batch_size     =  list(map(int,[e.strip() for e in parser[section_name]['b'].split(',')]))
     param_grid = dict(  learn_rate = learn_rate, batch_size =batch_size, epochs =epochs, optimizer=optimizer,activation=activation,weight_constraint=weight_constraint,dropout_rate=dropout_rate)
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid = param_grid, n_jobs=1,verbose=1, cv=[(slice(None), slice(None))], refit= True)
 grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train,validation_data=(X_trainTest,y_trainTest), log_dir='./Graph', loss= training_lossHistory)
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, Keras doesn't have any code to do Grid Search. PS: Don't post code as images.

Comment: You can use four spaces or ` ticks to put code in your question. You should post more of your code to give us a better idea of how you're setup. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask